# dotnet ef migrations {name} dotnet ef database update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am learning Entity Framework core and code first today, by following a video on pluralsite to create my own dbcontext.
My project does create a database, but it is not doing it in SQL Server.  When I create a context instance and look, it says database facade so I assume it is in memory.
Where can I change a flag, or set a digit somewhere in the thousands of lines of boiler plate of dot net core, to make it create the database in sql server, and not in memory?

I used the command line to attempt to create it.
dotnet ef migrations {name} dotnet ef database update

Answer (score 1):

You can tell your DbContext to work with SQL Server (or any provider) in your dbContext. You can do this in two ways:

1. By using dependency injection
2. By overriding the OnConfiguring method
       (Override in your Context class)

This is an example of overriding the OnConfiguring method

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
{
    string connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=YourDataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=true;"
    optionbuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
}
```

Be sure to check out
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html
and https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/sql-server/index.html for more info